# How to make 2 columns in loop data

Tags: php, html, css, foreach

I do foreach loop to output my data so my data will be like this

- Dog
- Cat
- Mouse
- Bird
- Egg
- Eagle
- Fish

using this code

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <?php foreach ($treefields as $key=>$item): ?>
      <?php if($key==0);?>

      <?php if($item['title'] == $estate_data_option_1057): ?>
      <div class="additional-amenities">
      <span class="available"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i></span><strong> <?php echo $options_name_1057; ?>:</strong><?php echo $estate_data_option_1057;?></span>
      </div>
      <?php if (count($item['childs_4']) > 0) foreach ($item['childs_4'] as $child): ?>
      <div class="additional-amenities">
      <span class="available"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i></span><strong><?php _che($child['description']); ?></strong><span><?php echo $child['title']; ?></span>
      </div>

      <?php endforeach; ?>
      <?php else: ?> 
      <?php  ?>   
      <?php endif;?>

      <?php endforeach; ?>   </div></div>
```

How can i make it 2 columns like this?

```
 - Dog      - Egg
 - Cat      - Eagle
 - Mouse    - Fish
 - Bird
```

Comment: You have a </span> matching nothing: `</span><?php echo $estate_data_option_1057;?></span>`

Comment: Create a variable outside the foreach loop and increment this. Then when that variable reaches 2, you reset it.

Comment: Did one of the answers help you? Please accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

First count the number of items in your array, then figure out what half of that would be and `ceil` it, so it's not a float.  Then use that value in a conditional to echo your markup to break it into multiple columns.

For example, here is the technique boiled down to put the array into two different `ul` elements.

```
<ul>
<?php
$animals = array('Dog','Cat','Mouse','Bird','Egg','Eagle','Fish');
$numAnimals = count($animals);
$maxAnimalsPerColumn = ceil($numAnimals/2);

for($i=0; $i < $numAnimals; $i++) {
    echo "<li>".$animals[$i]."</li>";
    if ($i+1 == $maxAnimalsPerColumn ) {
        echo "</ul><ul>";
    }
}
?>
</ul>
```

`$numAnimals` would be 7

`$maxAnimalsPerColumn` would be 4 (`$numAnimals` divided by 2, ceil'd)

When the loop value (plus 1 since it starts at zero) matches `$maxAnimalsPerColumn`, it will echo a closing `ul` tag and a new one to start the second.

**The resulting markup would be roughly:**

```
<ul>
  <li>Dog</li>
  <li>Cat</li>
  <li>Mouse</li>
  <li>Bird</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Egg</li>
  <li>Eagle</li>
  <li>Fish</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a counter. Example:

```
$nbrOfColumns = 2;
$rowsPerColumn = ceil(count($treefields)/$nbrOfColumns);
$counter = 1;

<div class="col-md-6">

foreach ($treefields as $key=>$item){

if($counter === $rowsPerColumn){
echo "</div><div class="col-md-6">";
$counter = 0;
}

(generate your HTML here)

$counter++;
}

</div>
```

Comment: I try your suggestion but nothing happen still same output

`foreach ($query->result() as $row)
  $r =  explode(",", $row->fa_am);
  $numcr = 2; 
  $numr = ceil(count($r)/$numcr);
  $counter = 1;
{
 echo '<div class="col-md-6">';
        foreach($r as $i) {

        if($counter === $numr){
        echo "</div><div class=col-md-6>";
        }
        echo '<div class="additional-amenities">';
        echo '<span class="available"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> </span><strong>'.$i.'</strong>';
        echo '</div>';
        $counter++;
        }
        echo '</div>'; `